# "screen.getByRole", Unable to find an accessible element with the role. But the element is there

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I don't understand how the role "div" was not found then the code follows to say there are not one but lots of "div"s, I tried to substitute the div for a "h5" seeing there is only one but returns the test pretty much the same error. What am I doing wrong?

I know that the error is in the line `const div = screen.getByRole("div");` because if I comment it the test is all green.

Error:

```js
  ● <CardInfo /> › should render the card

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "div"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      heading:

      Name "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.":
      <h5
        class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5 css-14ksg3c-MuiTypography-root"
      />

      --------------------------------------------------

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiCard-root css-1xez8po-MuiPaper-root-MuiCard-root"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiBox-root css-0"
          >
            <h5
              class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5 css-14ksg3c-MuiTypography-root"
            >
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
            </h5>
            <p
              class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 css-ahj2mt-MuiTypography-root"
            >
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quae aperiam voluptates distinctio aspernatur? Provident totam rerum dolorum hic et!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

       6 |     render(<CardInfo />);
       7 |
    >  8 |     const div = screen.getByRole("div");
         |                        ^
       9 |     // expect(div).toBeInTheDocument();
      10 |   });
      11 | });

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/cardInfo/cardInfo.spec.jsx:8:24)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

this is my "cardInfo.spec.jsx" file:

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { CardInfo } from ".";

describe("<CardInfo />", () => {
  it("should render the card", () => {
    render(<CardInfo />);

    const div = screen.getByRole("div");
    // expect(div).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This is my component:

```js
import { Typography, Box, Card } from "@mui/material";

export const CardInfo = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }}>
        <Box>
          <Typography variant={"h5"} sx={{ fontWeight: 800 }}>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quae
            aperiam voluptates distinctio aspernatur? Provident totam rerum
            dolorum hic et!
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to make lot's of tests of the component to train how I should make tests, but I don't really get why this frist one is with this error, seems ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jest doesn't find the role, usually it shows what roles are accessible on the html, and for your case:

```js
Here are the accessible roles:
   
   heading:

      Name "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.":
      <h5
        class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5 css-14ksg3c-MuiTypography-root"
      />
```

So, the role you are looking for is `heading`:

```js
screen.getByRole("heading");
```